# Error:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error: , while compiling:

Tags: android, sqlite

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,no,name,lastname FROM mytable WHERE " +
                                   "id = (SELECT MIN(id) and no=0 FROM mytable ); ",null);
```

I am getting that error at below, Could you please help me ?

What I want is to retrieve the record that has min Id where no=0 in the mytable....

> Error:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error: , while compiling:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing too many specifics about sqlite syntax, I'd guess your subquery isn't formatted quite right.

Try

```
SELECT id, no, name, lastname FROM mytable WHERE
       id = (SELECT min(ID) FROM mytable WHERE no = 0)
```

or

```
SELECT id, no, name, lastname FROM mytable WHERE
       id = (SELECT min(ID) FROM mytable) AND no = 0
```

depending on what your interpretation was (but it sounds like the first one). The first will return rows with the minimum `id` with also a `no` of 0, but the second query will return the minimum `id` and *then* use it to select for a row with a `no` of 0.

Comment: +1 - however, you might want to add an explanation of what the difference is between the two statements to further clarify. :)

Comment: Thanks, I've made that edit (which hopefully didn't confuse things further). I also just checked it out in sqlite3 on my local machine and it seems to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I tried that one, Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,no,name,lastname FROM mytable WHERE id = (SELECT min(ID) FROM mytable WHERE no = 0);",null); But still, I have an error message.....android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: You should move on to first row in the cursor by calling Cursor cur = db.raqQuery("Select * from myTable",null);
if (cur != null) {
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Name"))); // "Name" is the field name in table
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
}

Comment: Actually, I am getting the error right after cursor line int no = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("no")); Do you think Why ?

Comment: it is because the cursor is initially pointing to row at index -1 but actual row starts from index 0. Calling moveToFirst() will move the cursor to index 0.